# Jquery JSON Request Help - I'm able to get the Array, but not able to display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to use an API that gets information about ARK servers, like amount of people online and what not. Anyways the API is here https://api.ark.bar/server/192.99.18.156/27027 ...

I'm currently able to get the array using a simple script I came across, however I'm not familiar with jQuery. Or JSON for that matter. Here's my code below. I'd like to at least be able to alert the array. I think if I can get it alerted then I should know where to go from there for getting the array displayed on my website. I can tell it's working, as when I load my site, it logs the object along with all the information displayed on the api page.

On a side note the very last part with "$.each", I have edited those lines quite a few times trying to figure out how to use the array.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you

```js
myObject = {
  getArray: function(callback) {
     $.ajax({
      cache: true,
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://api.ark.bar/server/192.99.18.156/27027",
      success: function (data){
        callback.call(this,data);
      }
    });
  }
};

myObject.getArray(function(data) {
 console.log(data);
});

$.each(this, function(key, value) {
  alert(key + ": " + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And did you open the console? Were there any errors (probably are).

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Exactly, for instance `javascript: console.log(data);` is a syntax error.

Comment: Alright so I completely removed that console log and replaced it with "alert(JSON.stringify(data));" as someone had suggested in their answer.

This displays all the information that I need, but not how I am needing it. I am needing to be able to take individual pieces of the array to display on my website. Like say the server name which shows as just 'name'. I've tried dot operators and it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this plunkr example, hope this helps you with the game. I've console logged some of the data and printed out the game title into the h1 element, where you can take this further and decorate the view as you need.

http://plnkr.co/edit/AdlatVZbmPUgwQby1faF?p=preview

```
myObject.getArray(function(data) {
    var serverData = data.server;
    console.log('data object: ', serverData);
    console.log('game title: ', serverData.game);
    console.log('player count: ', serverData.playerCount);
    console.log('player 0 name: ', serverData.players[0].name);
    alert('game title' + serverData.game);
    $('h1').html(serverData.game);
});
```

If you look up dot notation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), it will help explain how to access data from javascript objects.

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I was looking for. I know how dot notation works, it's just not something I've used much. I also had no clue how to even get the different items from the array :/

Thank you so much, I should be able to build off from this and get what I need taken care of.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :) Good luck with the game, it sounds great!

Answer (score -1):

use JSON.stringify(data) to output the JSON array as a string.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: So I made some edits to my script and was able to get it to alert it as a string. However I am only wanting to take certain parts of the array to display on my site. If I turn it all in to one big string, wouldn't that make what I'm wanting to do, not possible?

Comment: Nope. The way you asked the question sounded like you wanted to just see the output of the request, and your console log lead me to believe you were just debugging ("I would like to be able to at least alert the array"). Are you asking how to iterate the key/value pairs in the JSON array?